# Filtering 2 arrays with React Reselect

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash, reselect

I'm using [React Reselec](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors)t and I'm trying to filter the selectedClients such that I only return clients.all that have id's from selectedClientsIds.

selected_clients.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const clientSelector = state => state.clients.all
const selectedClientSelector = state => state.selectedClientIds

const getClients = (all, selectedClientIds) => {
    const selectedClients = _.filter(
        all,
        client => _.contains(selectedClientIds, all.id)
    );

   return selectedClients;
};

export default createSelector(
    clientSelector,
    selectedClientSelector,
    getClients
);
```

The clients.all store looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": “Bob”,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": “Mary ”,
    }
]
```

The selectedClientIds store looks like this:

```
[1]
```

How would I combine both to only show a list of clients that have id's from selectedClientId's? With the filter I have above, I keep getting an empty array

```
 []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `client.id` not `all.id`

```
const getClients = (all, selectedClientIds) => {
    const selectedClients = _.filter(
        all,
        client => _.contains(selectedClientIds, client.id)
    );

   return selectedClients;
};
```